# Make Cypress listen to random DOM changes?

Tags: cypress

I have an application where a random popup message (NOT chrome popup message but a built in popup in the HTML) can suddenly appear.

If it appears, I cannot continue my test. I need to close the popup before I continue.

How can I make Cypress listen to these random DOM popups and close them automatically when they appear?

Comment: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/conditional-testing#Element-existence

Answer (score 0):

Cleanest way would be to change your application not to show the popup when it is running in Cypress mode. The best practice of detecting Cypress mode is checking if the `Cypress` object is exposed to the window or not.

```js
// in your application code
if (window.Cypress) {
  // logic that prevents the popup
}
```

Comment: I can't modify the application's code. Is there anything else that can be done?

Comment: When the popup can appear? You could actually have a simple `if` that checks if the popup is there if `true` close popup if not, do nothing, but actually the best way is to collaborate with a developer (development is covered by quality assurance as well) and add that preventing popup logic to the code.